# values for the intent remain the updated one when making multiple notification for push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

I am making an app which requires me to send multiple push notifications to users which has distinct values which will be shows when user click on them from status bar.

I am making the intent using the below code

```
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notification = new Notification();
     notification.when = when;
      notification.icon = icon;
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,RecentStoryPage.class);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id_leader);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "", intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;          
     // Play default notification sound
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;          
     // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;        
     notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(id), notification);
```

When I send single notification, this does not make any issues however whenever I make multiple notifications, whichever notification I click on, it always opens with the recent value.

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake, I made this line error full

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

which I should have made to

```
 PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Integer.parseInt(id), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```